# why connect refused when bind 0.0.0.0 using ssh port forward

Tags: ssh

I am using this command to port forward in my local machine:

```
ssh -L 3409:0.0.0.0:3309 -N -f user@80.110.35.85
```

after run this command, I could connect remote `80.110.35.85` successfully. But when I using another PC in the same local network, it tell me connection refused. This make me confusing, why did this happen? is it possible to using the port 3409 on other computer in the same local network?

Comment: Note `0.0.0.0` in your code has nothing to do with the listening end. If you did `-L 0.0.0.0:3409:0.0.0.0:3309` then the *first* `0.0.0.0` would. Frankly I have never thought of using [`0.0.0.0`](https://superuser.com/q/949428/432690) as destination. `127.0.0.1` as destination? -- yes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly what happens when you try "sing another PC in the same local network". What command are you running, or how did you configure the software that's failing, and how exactly does it fail. Tell us the exact error message.

Answer (score 3):

On the machine that is supposed to share the port with other hosts on the LAN, enable Gateway Ports in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf`  and restart sshd service.

```
GatewayPort yes
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! This is really-really useful!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. It should work from your local machine as well as any other machine that can reach your local machine in your network as long as you don't have any firewall on your local machine preventing port 3409.

```
ssh -L *:3409:80.110.35.85:3309 -N -f user@80.110.35.85
```